# How to append data in nsmutable dictionary

Tags: ios, swift, nsmutabledictionary

I want to add "SAT","SUN" after FRI with seperator comma, under "selected _days" how can I do it. is it possible to append values like that in NSmutable dictonary

```
   {
        "seleted_days" =     (
            FRI
        );
        timings =     (
                    (
            ),
                    (
            ),
                    (
            ),
                    (
            ),
                    (
                            {
                    "close_time" = "02:00 AM";
                    "open_time" = "01:00 AM";
                    timelist = "01:00 AM , 02:00 AM";
                    timestat = "1,1";
                }
            ),
                    (
            ),
                    (
            )
        );
    }
```

Comment: Inside NSMutableDictionary for selected_days key save an array with values "FRI", "SAT", "SUN"

Comment: @PuneetSharma For my requirement I need to append it dynamically

Comment: What do you mean by in between?

Comment: As already mentioned in the comments to your previous question don’t use `NSMutableDictionary` in swift at all. And in the answer to your previous question I showed you a way to parse the JSON. So it should be pretty easy to get the array containing the weekdays and add items.

Comment: @vadian I am changing someone else code thats why.if I changed it I need to change everything